# SQL Server 2005 Account Locked (user: sa) And Connection Limits

Tags: sql-server-2005, authentication, account, locked

A bunch of us at work use the user: sa account concurrently to do stuff. Then all of a sudden we got locked out.

Why did we get locked out?  And then it fixed itselft (we did close some connections).  Why did this happen?

Also, how do you find out the number of connected users?

Comment: maybe, how do i find that out?

Answer (score 1):

Could be someone is trying to log in with the wrong password.

The server could be set to lock the account for X-minutes after 3 failed attempts.

**EDIT:**

We are still in the stone ages here (SQL Server 2000), and I confess that I do not spend much time doing this. I always contact our System Administrator (SA) about these issues.

You may have better luck asking about things such as this on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

The lock could also be on the user account in your network (outside of the Server). To unlock user accounts on our Active Directory, I use a tool our SA handed to me:

[image: Active Directory Screen Shot]

Comment: Yeah how do i check on the permissions for x-minutes lock (where would that be?) also the web apps that we have on the servers never got locked out either

Comment: I edited a little, Chris. I hope it pans out for you. I'm out of my element here, though.